# finding essential right ideals in a ring

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Definition: A submodule $N$ of an $R$-module $M$ is said to be essential if, $N\cap K\neq0$ for every nonzero submodule $K$ of $M$.

My Question: Let $M$ be an $R$-module. If $N$ is an essential submodule of $M$, then for any $x \in M$, $N_x=\{r\in R|rx\in N\}$ is an essential left ideal in $R$.

My attempt: Let $I$ be a nonzero left ideal of $R$, then we show that $N_x\cap I\neq 0$. If possible let $N_x\cap I\neq 0$, then ?

I an stuck in finding a contradiction. Please help me.

Comment: I reckon that $N_x$ is a **left** ideal, not a right ideal.

Comment: sorry. Now, i have corrected it.

Comment: You don't need a proof by contradiction to show this. If $I$ is a left ideal of $R$, then what can you say about the subset $Ix = \{rx \mid r\in I\} \subseteq M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use this characterization:

$N$ is essential in $M$ iff for every $m\in M\setminus N$ there exists an $r\in R$ such that $rm\in N\setminus \{0\}$.

So wlog let $y\in R\setminus N_x$.

Then $yx\in M\setminus N$. Therefore there exists $z\in R$ such that $zyx\in N\setminus\{0\}$.  This means $zy\in N_x\setminus \{0\}$. By the characterization above, $N_x$ is essential in $R$.